# C# SendKey to MS-DOS Application

Tags: c#, legacy

I need to drive a legacy DOS application through SendKey in C#. However, I found that it didn't work.

From http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=39626, I understand that SendKey doesn't really works on MS-DOS application. All MS-DOS application receives is "\" when SendKey is called.

However, the forum points to [MSDN Article 142819](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q142819/), which utilizes Clipboard to push the keys into the MS-DOS application. An VB sample is given but I don't know how to translate it to C#.

Anyone has or know any similar example that is written in C# that I can refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) ([pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html)) instead. You will need to set the console window to be the foreground window using [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx) ([pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetForegroundWindow.html)) and then call it.

Comment: Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista:This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.

Tried to use SendInput and it works pretty well. Now it drives the DOS application seamlessly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand question correctly, you can try to use [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) property to send keys. To obtain a Process object you can use one of GetProcessBy... methods.